# My Angular component is not being updated during validation

Tags: angular, validation

I have a component to display a validation message:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-msg',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="showItem()" [class]="'text-error-small {class}'"> 
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./error-msg.component.css']
})
export class ErrorMessageComponent {
  @Input() item: any;
  @Input() class = "";
  @Input() useTouched = true;

  showItem() {
    if(this.item.valid)
      return false;
    if(this.useTouched && ! this.item.touched)
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

The idea is to use it like this:

```
    <input class="p-1" myValidator [(ngModel)]="param.parameter" #sample/>
    <app-error-msg [item]="sample">
        Please enter a valid name.
    </app-error-msg>
```

Where myValidator is a validator (which works correctly.) The problem is that although the validator is called on each keystroke, the app-error-msg component does not re-evaluate the html. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the form control using the template variable export (`#sample="ngModel"`), for `ngModel` directive, it supports the export of NgModel using the name as `ngModel`, In the source code ( [`ng_model.ts: 137`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) we can see this. Once we export this your validator seems to work fine!

main.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ErrorMsgComponent } from './error-msg/error-msg.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ErrorMsgComponent],
  template: `
    <input class="p-1" myValidator [(ngModel)]="name" #sample="ngModel" required/>
    <app-error-msg [item]="sample">
        Please enter a valid name.
    </app-error-msg>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

error msg

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-msg',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="showItem()" [class]="'text-error-small' + class"> 
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ErrorMsgComponent {
  @Input() item: any;
  @Input() class = '';
  @Input() useTouched = true;

  showItem() {
    if (this.item.valid) return false;
    if (this.useTouched && !this.item.touched) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g3p5cy?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ferror-msg%2Ferror-msg.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)